# YouTube api, Chrome extensions, youtube developer key and 403 Forbidden quota errors

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension, youtube, youtube-api, quota

I am creating a browser extension (Chrome/FF/Safari/Opera) for YouTube using the YouTube api.

The extension gets all of a users videos and searches through each of the videos last comments 1000 comments (because of the api limits this). It then displays comments that match a certain criteria. (That is those that contain links).

I initially had the videos in chunks of 100's but due to getting 403 forbidden quota exceeded responses I reduced this to video 50 which wasn't enough so reduced it again to 25.

I also use a javascript setTimeout between each video to try and spread the api requests. Initially this was 2 seconds but I have steadily increased it until I am now at 7 seconds. This long wait has obviously made my functionality a somewhat tedious experience for users although I am just about there and not getting the 403's anymore.

**So my questions are:**

**Is this to be expected from the api?**

**What can I do to improve this?**

**Would a developer key help here (or is it even possible yo use one in an extension)?**

In terms of the developer key I have watched a youtube api video which discussed that developer keys will reduce the chance of quota exceeded responses. But I also think that this is not something that can be used in an extension. I am not using my own server or website for my extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you don't use an API key, you will be bound to IP quotas. Using API/developers keys is the best practice.

There is no reason for you not to use it. You can put it inside your code simply.

You can get your key from here: https://cloud.google.com/console#/project

CORRECTION: URL for YouTube developer key is:

http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/dashboard/

Comment: Thanks. But what is to stop another developer grabbing the source code (which is very easy in extensions) and using my developer key?

Comment: I understand your concerns but this is a free api, so even if another developer steals is, it's not gonna give him any advantage.

Comment: Ok thanks for the advice. I guess I don't understand why they bother with the key seeing as its free. My source code is open source and I know at least one person who is working with it. So if they infinite loop requests with my key then maybe YouTube will block requests from my own app.

Plus couldn't YouTube do something to protect that? Say by having some kind of response key stored on my own website which the YouTube api would check against when requests are made with my key.

But you are correct the api is free and the key is free so I will just go ahead and use it. Thanks.

Comment: You also have a redirect address for your project with your key setup. So they can't really get to use your key. Whatever they try to do will redirect to your site.

Comment: Umm...I don't understand that. How does that redirect work exactly? It's not like my code is on my website. It's in an extension. At what point does it redirect? I have never been redirected to the site I entered on the develop key form.